# NMake under KDevelop (Win7) : error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, linker-errors, nmake, kdevelop

I have an existing project that I didn't know how to create a vs solution from it. So I decided to use KDevelop which can parse the directory and use the `CMakeLists.txt`.

The thing is that cmake can't find some lib files for the linking. The directory that these files are stored is in `PATH`. At first I thought that I might be compiling for another ARCH but I don't know where to go from here.

````
    C:/Users/Petros/projects/QtDice/build> "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Program Files (x86)/QtDice" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" C:/Users/Petros/projects/QtDice
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26730.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Petros/projects/QtDice/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"nmake" "/nologo" "cmTC_c2fa6\fast"
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir\build
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c2fa6.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
        C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1415~1.267\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe @C:\Users\Petros\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8F3F.tmp
    testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_c2fa6.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1415~1.267\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\Petros\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9088.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1415~1.267\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_c2fa6.exe /implib:cmTC_c2fa6.lib /pdb:C:\Users\Petros\projects\QtDice\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c2fa6.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_c2fa6.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Petros/projects/QtDice/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Petros/projects/QtDice/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
*** Failure: Exit code 1 ***
```
````

Are there any ideas on what could be wrong?

EDIT : **SOLVED**

At last I found a rather hackish workaround. The batch file for KDevelop in VS enviroment, doesn't work for VS-2017 (which defined the `VS150COMNTOOLS` variable) but it supports up to VS-2015 (`VS140COMNTOOLS`).

VS2017 changed the layout of it's folders so the old `SET script="!base!\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"` really becomes `SET script="%base%..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64`.

Of course this new script should be run inside `Developer Command Prompt` console and not by just clicking the batch file.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions

if DEFINED VS150COMNTOOLS (
    SET "base=%VS150COMNTOOLS%"
) else ( IF DEFINED VS120COMNTOOLS (
    SET "base=%VS120COMNTOOLS%"
) else ( IF DEFINED VS110COMNTOOLS (
    SET "base=%VS110COMNTOOLS%"
) else ( IF DEFINED VS100COMNTOOLS (
    SET "base=%VS100COMNTOOLS%"
) else (
    START CMD /C "The Microsoft Visual C++ compiler was not found on your system, you might not be able to compile programs. && PAUSE"
) )))

SET script="%base%..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
CALL %script%

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\KDE\KDevelop" /v Install_Dir`) DO (
    set appdir=%%A %%B
)

if NOT DEFINED appdir (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\KDE\KDevelop" /v Install_Dir`) DO (
        set appdir=%%A %%B
    )
)

START "" "%appdir%\bin\kdevelop.exe"
```

Comment: Try deleting `build` directory from the project's root and then running KDevelop in Visual Studio environment (there is a link for that).

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing but without luck. I found out that cmake doens't find MSVC.

Comment: Yep, so it is not KDevelop problem. Try running `Visual Studio Installer`, making sure everything is up-to-date and C++ components are installed.

Comment: I think it's a `PATH` issue because now running `cl` from `Developer Command Prompt` gives me an error of [`application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/122b22d7-0888-471a-b834-1c4c338679ff/clexe-failing-with-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b?forum=vcgeneral). Thank you :)

Comment: Error `0xc000007b` disappeared as soon as I took care of the messed up `PATH` and logoff.

Comment: @Petross404: Could you file a patch for this? Please see https://www.kdevelop.org/contribute-kdevelop how to submit one.

Comment: @kfunk : Well, I can try.